# Haystack Whoosh not indexing everything

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I am using Haystack v1.0 and Whoosh v1.8.1 to build a customized search engine for my website. Everything works beautifully but the problem is that I get no results for a lot of entries in my indexed models.

For e.g. - I have four registered models - Member, Guest, Event, Sponsor. On rebuilding index from django shell, following happens:

./manage.py rebuild_index

```
Indexing 26 members.  
Indexing 3 events.
Indexing <x> guests.  
Indexing <y> sponsors.
```

But on running the SearchQuery API commands and also on searching through the search page, I cannot search half the member names. What eludes me is that when I can search 14-15 members, why not the rest. My template *_text.txt* file should be correct since half the members are getting indexed correctly.

You can try this
[http://www.edciitr.com/search/?q=**x**](http://www.edciitr.com/search/?q=Akshit)
x= **Vikesh** returns 1 result (as expected)
x= **Akshit** returns no results (the problem!)

Both values 'Akshit' and 'Vikesh' were present prior to rebuild_index. Here's the list of all 26 members that I am trying to search - http://www.edciitr.com/contact/

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so here's what I did to find out whether the problem is in Whoosh or Haystack. I opened the django shell and performed a search for the term that was not showing up in haystack SearchQuery API search:

```
./manage.py shell   
$>> import whoosh 
$>> from whoosh.query import *  
$>> from whoosh.index import open_dir
$>> ix = open_dir('/home/somedir/my_project/haystack/whoosh/')  
$>> ix.schema  
<Schema: ['branch', 'category', 'coordinator', 'date_event', 'designation','details', 'django_ct', 'django_id'> 'name', 'organisation', 'overview','text', 'title']>
$>> searcher = ix.searcher()  
$>> res = searcher.search(Term('text',u'akshit'))  
$>> print res  
<Top 1 Results for Term('text', 'akshit') runtime=0.000741004943848>
$>> print res['0']['name']  
u'Akshit Khurana'
```

So you see, Whoosh is correctly indexing all data. So, now I try the SearchQuery API

```
./manage.py shell
 $>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
 $>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content='akshit')
 $>> sqs
 $>> []
```

So, I realize that I must check out the whoosh_backend.py file of the haystack library to see what's happening. Open - `haystack.backends.whoosh_backend around line number 345`

```
'''Uncomment these two lines because the raw_results set becomes empty after the filter     call for some queries''  
if narrowed_results:
      raw_results.filter(narrowed_results)
```

to

```
#if narrowed_results:
      #raw_results.filter(narrowed_results)
```

And then it works. SearchQueryAPI returning exactly one result for the test query as expected. Web search working but I would like to know what's the issue with haystack here.

Comment: Hey Vikesh, did you ever figure out what went wrong? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Not really, I am sorry. Couldn't find the time to investigate it further, but if you only want to solve the problem, you can look at the answer above.

Comment: I am having the same issue, except it worked in the morning and not working in the afternoon, tried switch to xapian and returned the records fine. Something to do with whoosh.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar symptom, and this is the question I asked [Django django-haystack cannot import CategoryBase from django-categories on the first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196183/django-django-haystack-cannot-import-categorybase-from-django-categories-on-the)

Might relate to your problem too.